# Cannot run bash script via php possible permissions

Tags: centos7, apache2, shell, lamp, ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg installed on a CentOS 7 machine running a standard LAMP stack. I can run ffmpeg fine by itself in a terminal, like so:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:password@10.0.0.152/play2.sdp" camera1.mp4
```

I have a php script more or less like the following:

```
<?php
$camerabash = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:password@10.0.0.152/play2.sdp" camera1.mp4');
echo $camerabash;
?>
```

The following gives me an echoed result of "apache":

```
<?php
$camerabash = shell_exec('whoami');
echo $camerabash;
?>
```

I think I have a permissions problem, and I've explored a few options including editing the http.conf file, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: httpd error log is as follows: 

        title           : Session streamed by D-Link
    comment         : play2.sdp
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x352, q=2-31, 15.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, mono
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (copy)
    Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (copy)
    Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Permission denied

Comment: You may add the 2>&1 at the end of the command to catch errors

Comment: So Apache can't write in camera1.mp4 file. You can try "touch ('camera1.mp4');" to see if it works

Comment: Last line or error returned reads as follows: 
camera1.mp4: Permission denied

Comment: OK, now check the audit log.